# QGIS Modeler - cannot use aggregate function in this context?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I am using QGIS 3.22 and
I am making some algorithm in Modeler
[image]

I am using Vector Layer as *layer* and Vector Field as *field* (it is field with *real* values and nulls). I want to add column with sum of *field*. So in Field calculator I use following formula

[image: *sum(@]

As a result I get NULL field instead of my input field and the following error message is shown:

> Eval Error: Cannot use aggregate function in this context.

How to use aggregate functions correctly?

[image]

Comment: Please provide relevant error messages.

Comment: @Erik Eval Error: Cannot use aggregate function in this context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit tricky in QGIS - may be it is an error because it is not logical, which QGIS mostly is - but anyway, you have to change your formula to `precalculated value` and then make a string representation of your formula like:

```
'sum(' || @field || ')'
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm!